# Getting the image attributes of all images within a section class

Tags: user-interface, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the attributes of all the images that are present inside a section class. The images attributes I'm trying to get are :

1. Image height.
2. Image width
3. Image src

I am trying to achieve using Selenium Webdriver.

I'm new to Selenium, so I went through web tutorials and various answers provided on the internet.

My code goes like this :

```
 public void findAllImages(){
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

baseUrl="http://northeastindiaholidays.com/";
driver.get(baseUrl);


WebElement menu=driver.findElement(By.className("destinations clearfix full"));
List<WebElement> allImages=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));


List<String> widthofImage = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> heightofImage = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> srcofImage = new ArrayList<String>();

for (WebElement imageFromList: allImages){
     widthofImage.add(imageFromList.getAttribute("width"));
       heightofImage.add(imageFromList.getAttribute("height"));
      srcofImage.add(imageFromList.getAttribute("src"));

      System.out.println(widthofImage);
      System.out.println(heightofImage);
      System.out.println(srcofImage);

     }

 }
 }
```

The page html looks like this :

```
   <section class="destinations clearfix full" style="margin-bottom:10px!important">
   <h1>Beach Destinations</h1>
   <article class="location_item one-fourth fluid-item">
   <figure>
   <a title="" href="http://northeastindiaholidays.com/?location=goa">
   <img width="270" height="152" alt="" src="http://northeastindiaholidays.com/wp-    content/uploads/2014/06/Goa.gif"/>
  </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="details">
  </article>
```

The URL of the page is :  [North East India Holidays](http://northeastindiaholidays.com/)

Comment: So do you have a question?

Comment: Yeah, I am realizing that I completely missed out on describing the problem. I am getting an error in selecting the classname using the destination section class.
Here's the link to the image of the error that I'm getting 

[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3aMk3yP4IBFNW8tV0FqRXRPWnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit the original post with new information. Also: did you actually take a screenshot of a text window? Why?

Comment: I think the error says it all: "Compound class names are not supported." Probably in this line: `driver.findElement(By.className("destinations clearfix full"));`. The rest of the error output tells you the solution.

Comment: Understood that error message. Is there any alternate solution to this problem. can I do it in any other way?

Comment: Yes, use a different selector, such as XPath.

Comment: Use CSS selector ".destination.clearfix.full". This will find any element with all 3 classes. It also works even if the order of the classes change.  Xpath is less forgiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.GetText;

public class Sample 
{       
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void BeforeClass() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "default");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://northeastindiaholidays.com/");
    Thread.sleep(4000);

}
@Test
public void fetchCustKeys() throws Exception
{
    //WebElement menu1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/section[1]"));
    WebElement menu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/section[./h1[text()='Beach Destinations']]"));
    List<WebElement> allImages=menu.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

    List<String> widthofImage = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> heightofImage = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> srcofImage = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement imageFromList: allImages)
    {
        widthofImage.add(imageFromList.getAttribute("width"));
        heightofImage.add(imageFromList.getAttribute("height"));
        srcofImage.add(imageFromList.getAttribute("src"));
    }
    System.out.println(widthofImage);
    System.out.println(heightofImage);
    System.out.println(srcofImage);
}
}
```

Other than the XPATH of the section, two more corrections are there in the code.

1) By using the above mentioned XPATH for the Section, you can reuse the XPATH just by changing the name of the section.
Eg:

```
WebElement menu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/section[./h1[text()='Beach Destinations']]"));
WebElement menu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/section[./h1[text()='Top destinations around North East India']]"));
```

2) By using the following statement you will get images in the whole web page.

```
List<WebElement> allImages=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
```

So we need to change the statement like below to   get the images of particular section:

```
List<WebElement> allImages=menu.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
```

3) Move the printing of `ArrayList`s out of the `for` loop

Output:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\HEMA\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-717955280\testng-customsuite.xml

[268, 268, 268, 268]
[152, 152, 152, 152]
[http://northeastindiaholidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Goa.gif, http://northeastindiaholidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Puducherry_beach.jpg, http://northeastindiaholidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Kerla.jpg, http://northeastindiaholidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Leh.jpg]
PASSED: fetchCustKeys

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@16754ffd: 469 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 1 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@21a2fefd: 303 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@391e680f: 94 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@7f7f5281: 154 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@60c4d1a7: 11 ms
```

Comment: Hi Hemasundar, the code that you mentioned is doing the same thing- it  prints all the images and their attributes present in the page.

Comment: @geeko_zac I have added the output, i am getting. How come you are getting wrong output. Copy the code properly & Try again.

Comment: Yeah it worked. Actually my eclipse was not running this program. Thanks a lot. You come to my rescue once again. Accepted this as the answer. Cheers